# How to display the view of virtual studio in WPF panel?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the code that starts the engine of external dll file and shows the view of virtual studio that is created in this dll file. The code runs perfectly in Windows Forms. Now when I try to use the same code in WPF, it complains about the final line that shows the output, and this line involves window handling. I am not that familiar with the code below and I do not know much about delegates and handling, but could somebody please help me make this run in WPF?

```
namespace MSShowTestGUI
    {
    public delegate void CallbackDelegate();
    public delegate void NotificationsCallbackDelegate(CinectorNotification message);

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    MSShowAPI.API instance = new API();

    //List<AudioDevice> audioDevices = new List<AudioDevice>();
    //List<CameraDevice> cameraDevices = new List<CameraDevice>();

    CallbackDelegate clickIntoDeleg;
    IntPtr clickIntoPointer;

    NotificationsCallbackDelegate notificationsCallbackDeleg;
    IntPtr notificationsCallbackPointer;

    bool engineRunning = false;

    public Form1()
    {   
        InitializeComponent();

        if (checkBox_autostart.Checked)
        {
            InitializeEngine2();
        }

        Application.Idle += Update;
        clickIntoDeleg = ClickIntoCallback;
        clickIntoPointer = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(clickIntoDeleg);
        instance.SetClickIntoCallback(clickIntoPointer);

        notificationsCallbackDeleg = NotificationsCallback;
        notificationsCallbackPointer = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(notificationsCallbackDeleg);
        instance.SetNotificationsCallback(notificationsCallbackPointer);


        //instance.SetNotificationsCallback()
    }   

    #region initialization

    private void InitializeEngine2()
    {
        UpdateControls();
        if (!engineRunning)
        {
            CallbackDelegate handler = ReadyCallback;
            IntPtr delegPointer = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(handler);

            instance.InitializeEngine(CinectorWindow.Handle, new Resolution(1920, 1080), 1000, delegPointer); //this line shows the view of the studio in a panel but in WPF there is no "CinectorWindow.Handle"          
        }        
    }

    protected void ReadyCallback()
    {
        engineRunning = true;
        instance.SetActiveStudio(0);

        UpdateControls();

        // called only first run?
        /*engineRunning = true;
        UpdateControls();*/
    }

    private void button_initEngine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitializeEngine2();
    }

    private void UpdateControls()
    {
        button_initEngine.Enabled = !engineRunning;

        button_killEngine.Enabled = engineRunning;
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        ShutdownEngine();
    }

    private void ShutdownEngine()
    {
        if (engineRunning)
        {
            instance.ShutdownEngine();
            engineRunning = false;
        }
        UpdateControls();
    }

    private void button_killEngine_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShutdownEngine();
    }

    #endregion

    private void ClickIntoCallback()
    {
        //code
    }

    private void NotificationsCallback(CinectorNotification notif)
    {
        notificationBox.AppendText("[" + notif.timestamp + "] " + notif.type + ": " +  notif.message + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    void Update(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        instance.Update();
    }


    private void CinectorWindow_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    }
    }
```

Comment: WPF and Windows Form controls have different properties.  Can you please point out exactly which line of code is causing the problem and what the exact error is?  It's very hard to tell what the actual problem is without those things

Comment: Yes, I put a comment next to that line. But here it is: instance.InitializeEngine(CinectorWindow.Handle, new Resolution(1920, 1080), 1000, delegPointer); It just complains that there is no Handle property for CinectorWindow which is a StackPanel.

Comment: Ah yes I see it now, the comment is off my screen so i couldn't see it.  StackPanels don't have a Handle property or method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.stackpanel(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, thanks. But what can I use instead?

Comment: I'll do some checkng, at work atm so it may take me a bit to get back to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Turns out that not only Windows have Handles.

There's a control named `WindowsFormsHost` that is used to host WinForms elements inside WPF views, and this control does have its own Handle property.

So you just have to change `CinectorWindow` and make it of type `WindowsFormsHost`, instead of a StackPanel, and use its Handle just like you're already doing in your question.

-- Original answer --

In WPF, only Windows have Handles, and there is no `Handle` property.

To get the Handle of your Window you need to do:

```
// "this" being the current Window
WindowInteropHelper windowHwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this);  
IntPtr hWnd = windowHwnd.Handle;
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without handles?

Comment: No, unless you're able to modify the `InitializeEngine` code and can explain us what that method does.

Comment: Unfortunatelu I'm not. The method is internal in dll and it loads the deafult inital state of the program. SO you are saying that whatever I saw displayed in a Paint panel in Windows Form, now I can see only in new window in wpf?

Comment: I think I may have found an option... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Done! Just make your `CinectorWindow` a WindowsFormsHost and you're set, hopefuly.